# How to perform subtraction in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am fresher in php and making library management project. I want to print total books in library,For that i have used the following code:

```
<?php
$query ="select sum(copies) as totalbooks from booksdetail";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['totalbooks'];     
}
?>
```

I want to print total no of books that are issued, for that i have used the  following code:

```
<?php
$query ="select count(id) as issuedbooks from issue";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['issuedbooks'];     
}
?>
```

Now, I want to print number of books available in library, for that i have to subtract `issued books` from the `total books`.

Please suggest which code should i use for subtraction?

Comment: `$available = $row['totalbooks'] - $row['issuebooks']` ~ though it would be better to do the calculation in the db and have one query only.

Comment: this code prints the result= '0'  @RamRaider Sir

Comment: Ok, how about all in the db: `select( 
 ( select sum(copies) from booksdetail ) - ( select count(id) from issue ) 
) as 'available';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$totalBooks=0;
$query ="select sum(copies) as totalbooks from booksdetail";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $totalBooks=$row['totalbooks'];     
}?>

<?php
$issuedBooks=0;
$query ="select count(id) as issuedbooks from issue";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $issuedBooks=$row['issuedbooks'];     
}?>

<?
echo $availableBooks = $totalBooks - $issuedBooks;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is all:

```
<?php
    $query ="select sum(copies) as totalbooks from booksdetail";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $totalbooks = 0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $totalbooks = $row['totalbooks'];     
    }

    $query ="select count(id) as issuedbooks from issue";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);

$issuedbooks=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $issuedbooks= $row['issuedbooks'];     
    }

$sub_result = $totalbooks - $issuedbooks;
echo $sub_result;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? Querying it all on the database is much faster than making 2 queries and calculating it on the client

```
<?php
$query ="select (totalbooks.val - issuedbooks.val) as result from (select sum(copies) as val from booksdetail) totalbooks, (select count(id) as val from issue) issuedbooks";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['result'];     
}
?>
```